# error call to a member function paginate() on array Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I want to add Pagination to the user list, but an error occurred during Implementation. I use Codeigniter 4 and where using Query Builder,

But when I checked an error appeared:`Error Call to a member function paginate() on array`

User Controller :

```php
    public function index()
        {
            $builder = $this->db->table('akun');
            $builder->where('created_by', session()->get('nama'));
            $query = new AkunModel();
            $query = $builder->get()->getResult();
            $data = [
                'query' => $query->paginate(10, 'query'),
                'pager' => $this->AkunModel->pager,
                'currentPage' => $currentPage,
            ];
            return view('user/index', $data);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set up table in your model, see documentation

```
protected $table = "akun";
```

https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/models/model.html#configuring-your-model

```
public function index()
    {
        $builder = new AkunModel();
        $builder->where('created_by', session()->get('nama'));
        $data = [
            'query' => $builder->paginate(10),
            'pager' => $builder->pager,
            'currentPage' => $currentPage,
        ];
        return view('user/index', $data);
    }
```

// In the views:

```
<?= $pager->links() ?>
```